# In which year the notion of star death started?

Tags: physics, astronomy

In which year, does the fact: **every star will ultimately die** came in to existence?

Comment: Probably before the present meaning of "death of a star" came into existence, which probably makes this an ill-formed question as presently worded. For example, [the ancient Babylonians worshiped stars as gods](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/astral-religion) and presumably (I haven't looked into this) these gods could die, so would the ancient Babylonians be a possible answer to your question?

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yeah, although their terminology or approach is different, they are stating a fact only... So it can be a possible answer...

Comment: In more modern times, before the nucleosynthesis was discovered, the prime candidate for the energy source of stars was the [Kelvin–Helmholtz mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_mechanism) of gravitational contraction, which implied that every star will die, and that the Sun should have died long ago (when the age of Earth was estimated). Even before that [heat death of the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe#History) was already derived from the second law.

Comment: @hanugm   Stars never die because they never live.  Speaking about the lives of stars is using a metaphor.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Death here means falling away...

Comment: @M.A.Golding It started as a metaphor, but now is standard terminology among astronomers, see e.g. [NSF](https://public.nrao.edu/radio-astronomy/star-life-and-death/):"*Stars are not alive, and yet we speak of their origins and ends as “birth and death.” It’s a convenient, if fanciful, way of describing the ultimately ill-fated relationship between matter and energy that is a star.*" Physical term "work" also started as a metaphor, as did quark "colors", etc.